# In SPARQL do I create a construct to infer information before using a SELECT query?

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

I have the following information:

```
s:Marshmallow    rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android
```

```
s:galaxyEdge6    s:OS       s:Marshmallow;
                 s:price    350.
...
```

I need to be search for phones that are both Android and have a price > 400.

I have written:

```
CONSTRUCT {?phone rdf:type s:Android}
WHERE {?phone s:OS ?opSystem.
       ?opSystem rdfs:subClassOf s:Android.}

SELECT ?phone WHERE {
       ?phone rdf:type s:Android.
       ?phone s:price ?value.
       FILTER(?value < 400) }
```

I am not fully sure what the purpose of a construct is. I mean, is it a more complex form of querying; or is it something that helps define information for later querying (like what I have done above)?

I also do not know if what I have written is correct.

edit: left out `FILTER`

Comment: `CONSTRUCT` does nothing more than returning proper RDF triples. That's all. So, what you're doing is pre-processing your data here. If you add the new data to your existing dataset and  run the `SELECT` query on the enriched dataset, yes it will work. ( Indeed you have forgotten to add the `FILTER`)

Comment: Note, you cannot run both queries at once, this won't change anything - `CONSTRUCT` does not modify the dataset on which you're running the `SELECT` query - this step has to be done by yourself in advance